# TCP ACK delay on Android 3G

Tags: java, android, tcp, libgdx

I'm using LibGDX network libraries to send data from clients to my server.

Everything is working fine on a desktop client.

Everything is also working fine on an Android client connected through WiFi.

But, I got some strange problems on an Android client connected through a 3G connection.

Here is my server side code:

```
ServerSocketHints serverSocketHint = new ServerSocketHints();
serverSocketHint.acceptTimeout = 0;

ServerSocket serverSocket = Gdx.net.newServerSocket(Protocol.TCP, Parameters.getInstance().getServerPort(), serverSocketHint);

while(true)
{
    SocketHints socketHints = new SocketHints();
    socketHints.connectTimeout = 10000;

    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(socketHints);

    new ClientRequestsHandler(socket).start();
}
```

And here is the client side:

```
this.socketHints = new SocketHints();

try {
    this.socket = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(Net.Protocol.TCP, "8*********", 9021, socketHints);

    this.clientHandler = new ClientHandler(socket, this.aesImplementation);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Gdx.app.log("TCP CONNECTION",e.getMessage(),e);
}
```

The problem is that ACK packets seems to be delayed. I tried to disable Nagle algorithm with no success.

Here is a Wireshark capture:

[Screenshot of Wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrSgQ.png)

Does anyone know a workaround except switching to UDP?

I prefer not to use UDP since I don't need real-time and I need a reliable transmission.

Answer (score 0):

' if your server also was on the same wifi network I guess then this worked in a local network, and the problem comes when it comes to remote networks. Right ?

Comment: No, I tried at a friend house, using android & wifi, everyting is working fine. Problem seems to be tied with 3G connection.